# Require a specific element in a sequence of any elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to create a XSD like so:

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Explaination:

Element a required, inside the element:

- Any element 0 to infinity times.
- Element b 1 to infinity times.
- Any element 0 to infinity times.

I tried to use `choice`, `all` and etc, but I did not find any solution.

Error from XmlSpy:

> `<any...>` makes the content model non-deterministic against `<xs:element name="b" ...>`. Possible causes: name equality, overlapping occurrence
>   or substitution groups.

Comment: What error are you currently getting?  And where is the `name` attribute for your outer `<xs:element>` tag?

Comment: Can you post the code for where you use this XSD definition?

Comment: Sry, i added the name now. Error from XmlSpy: " <any...> makes the content model non-deterministic against <xs:element name="b" ...>. Possible causes: name equality, overlapping occurrence or substitution groups."

Comment: The `<any>` tags you have in there are causing a potential ambiguity which could occur when an XML file gets validated against your schema.  Read [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386377/ambiguous-xml-schema) for more information.  I don't have a quick solution to your problem at the moment.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will read the article. If any one else have an answer please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSD effectively is attempting to say that `a` can have any sequence of children elements as long as there is at least one `b` element.

XSD 1.0 cannot enforce such a constraint because any attempt to do so, including the one you offer, would violate the Unique Particle Principle.

XSD 1.1 could enforce such a constraint via a simple assertion stating that `b` exists among the `xsd:any` children of `a`.

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="b"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```